# Looking for a shorter term for "Preferred places to meet"

Tags: word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests, expression-choice

I am working on an online platform (mobile and web apps) that enable item lending/renting between peers. When a user posts an item for rent, he needs to put down his **preferred places to meet for item pickup/return**. Tentatively, we use *"preferred meetup locations"*. But I am not quite sure if that serves our purpose well because the word *meetup* gives me a sense of larger group gathering.

Is the current term suffice? If not, please provide suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like they don't even need to meet. They just need a *preferred exchange location*. (It even allows for someone else can handle the exchange.)

Comment: Sounds like an opportunity to be creative: meetpoint, dropspot... work in your brandname to get bonus points from the marketing department.

Comment: @CanisLupus - Thanks. I thought of using the word *exchange* but I think it might be a little imprecise in the case that a user is willing to lend out his item free of charge (a use case that we support). Maybe I am just being too picky. What's your take?

Comment: @John - You have got a point there. I will discuss this approach with my team here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the term you're looking for is - Rendezvous.

Comment: A rendezvous is an event, he wants the name of the place. "Rendezvous point" might work, though.

Comment: In that case I believe "Stamping ground" would serve the purpose.

Comment: @AndySemyonov No, it wouldn't. *Stamping ground* is a habitual locality (not specific place). "Hackney? That was my old stamping ground!"

Comment: @Parthian Shot _Rendezvous_ is also used to describe the venue. [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rendezvous) has: **rendezvous** (1.1) A meeting place:
_you’d be welcome to use this place as a rendezvous_ The 'preferred' requirement is not really met, though.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I stand corrected.

Comment: @ParthianShot -  Looking at the definition of **rendezvous**, it does seem to fit in with my intention. But I don't know if it's just me. The word somehow gives me a sense of an agreement has been made. Do you feel the same? If not, what do you think of "preferred rendezvous"? I have to admit that it sounds weird to me.

Comment: @tamakisquare Preferred rendezvous sounds awful to me. The term rendezvous has the connotation of of preferred, agreed, decided in advance, attached to it. I personally think it's as good a word as any you're going to find to describe the said condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need brevity here for the field name itself, maybe *locations*.  I suppose there will be a form to fill out.  In the html input box, you can display a helpful message, and that can be a little bit longer.  Also, on the page that explains how the system works, you can define *locations* more thoroughly.

If you feel *locations* is *too* short, you could say *possible locations*.

It is helpful to leave it rather general, because you want it to work from all points of view -- initial drop-off, initial pick-up, final drop-off, final pick-up.

If you want to get fancy, you could say *locus.*  But I'm sure it's better to stay away from fancy.